# I'm get the following error log when I try to install cryptodome

Tags: python, pip, cryptography, mingw, pycryptodome

I'm getting this error when i try to pip install cryptodome :

```
× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [17 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n9q1xfuw\pycryptodome_520086b2afc74db3bef1d6098b1acac3\setup.py", line 474, in <module>
          set_compiler_options(package_root, ext_modules)
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n9q1xfuw\pycryptodome_520086b2afc74db3bef1d6098b1acac3\compiler_opt.py", line 341, in set_compiler_options
          clang = compiler_is_clang()
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n9q1xfuw\pycryptodome_520086b2afc74db3bef1d6098b1acac3\compiler_opt.py", line 251, in compiler_is_clang
          return test_compilation(source, msg="clang")
        File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n9q1xfuw\pycryptodome_520086b2afc74db3bef1d6098b1acac3\compiler_opt.py", line 82, in test_compilation
          objects = compiler.compile([fname], extra_postargs=extra_cc_options)
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 343, in compile
          self.initialize()
        File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 246, in initialize
          raise DistutilsPlatformError(
      distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: --plat-name must be one of ('win32', 'win-amd64', 'win-arm32', 'win-arm64')
      Testing support for clang
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.   
error: metadata-generation-failed
```

Is this a problem with my ming compiler ?, Please help.

I tried upgrading my setuptools using

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with the python installation, I clean reinstalled python and was able to install the library successfully.